# AWARE method in ecoinvent through brightway2

Tags: brightway

i'm trying to extract all water inputs to several processes using brightway or ab, but i'm having troubles getting those values from the inventory_matrix. I need to get quantity of water consumed and origin of the water (surface, well, unspecified, tap water) along with its geography. mI'm using ecoinvent 3.7.1

One way i thought i could do that is create an impact assessment method with CFs for those compartments (each of those will be 1s), then apply it to the processes and analyse the elementary flows contributions.

I'm not sure though i can get the geography like this.

**EDITED MOST OF THE QUESTION FOR CLARITY**

Seems like i was trying to reinvent the wheel! My goal is to implement AWARE method and apply it to quite a few processes. the best result would be to use AWARE through activity-browser so i can use all of its functionalities which are very time-saving for me.

i just saw that there is [brightway2-regional](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-regional) and [bw2_aware](https://github.com/cmutel/bw2_aware) that implement the aforementioned method.

So i'm now trying to install the packages in my brightway2 conda environment.

Managed to get bw2regional through conda but i cant manage to install bw2_aware if not through pip.
managed to install bw2_aware by using the wheel file and pip install --no-deps and then tweaking a line in the source code for fiona import, now i'm getting errors when running

```
bwr.bw2regionalsetup()
bw2_aware.import_aware()
```

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pandarus.brightwaylca.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pandarus.brightwaylca.org' doesn't match either of '*.parkingcrew.net', 'parkingcrew.net'",),))
```

Now i'm trying to understand if i can apply this to ecoinvent, and how. i'm really unsure if i can add the different geographies to the elementary flows in the database, so that i can correctly calculte aware in a lca.
I already saw that importing AWARE allows to choose it as a impact cathegory in activity-browser, though i cannot see the geographies in the CFS shown in the Charaterization Factors tab.

[image: Screenshot from AB]

So i then tried to calculate an LCA with AB using AWARE method and 2 sample processes:

```
diesel, burned in agricultural machinery | diesel, burned in agricultural machinery | GLO | megajoule | ECOINVENT3.7.1

electricity, high voltage | market for electricity, high voltage | IT | kilowatt hour | ECOINVENT3.7.1
```

and i get this result (first is Agricultural, the other is non Agricultural):

```
diesel, burned in agricultural machinery | GLO
    0.014757994762941706    0.00654978730728395
market for electricity, high voltage | IT 0.285207979534988 0.12657895834095712
```

I wonder if this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to use regionalized calculations in the activity browser, and the AWARE method (incorrectly) relies on an external web service which is not strictly necessary. So the short answer is that this isn't possible right now, but as you are the second person to ask about this in a week, we need to get it working ASAP.

Comment: thats' very unfortunate, i'll be on the lookout for updates on bw2 and AB. Atm the only way to do this kind of calculations is through SimaPro or OpenLCA, right? the first one you have to pay fr it, for the latter, you need to pay for another license in order to use ecoinvent, even if you already have the license for it (the software uses a different format for imports).

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct - constructing an LCIA method is an easy way to do this. This is because there are unspoken assumptions behind these flows - they will be mostly positive numbers, but some represent consumption, while others represent release.

Here is an example using Brightway 2.5, it would need to be adapted for version 2:

```py
import bw2data as bd
import bw2calc as bc
import numpy as np

bd.projects.set_current("ecoinvent 3.7.1")
ecoinvent = bd.Database("ecoinvent 3.7.1")
beet = ecoinvent.search("beet")[1]

water_method = bd.Method(("Water", "raw"))
water_method.register()
water_method.write([(x, -1 if x['categories'][0] == 'natural resource' else 1) 
                    for x in bd.Database("biosphere3") 
                    if x['name'].startswith('Water')])

demand, data_objs, _ = bd.prepare_lca_inputs(demand={beet: 1}, method=("Water", "raw"))

lca = bc.LCA(demand=demand, data_objs=data_objs)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
coo = lca.characterized_inventory.tocoo()

results = sorted(zip(np.abs(coo.data), coo.data, coo.row, coo.col), reverse=True)
for a, b, c, d in results[:10]:
    print("{:.6f}\t{}\n\t\t{}".format(
        float(b), 
        bd.get_activity(lca.dicts.biosphere.reversed[c]), 
        bd.get_activity(lca.dicts.activity.reversed[d])
    ))
```

With the result:

```
0.009945    'Water' (cubic meter, None, ('water',))
            'electricity production, hydro, run-of-river' (kilowatt hour, CH, None)
-0.009945   'Water, turbine use, unspecified natural origin' (cubic meter, None, ('natural resource', 'in water'))
            'electricity production, hydro, run-of-river' (kilowatt hour, CH, None)
0.009514    'Water' (cubic meter, None, ('water',))
            'electricity production, hydro, run-of-river' (kilowatt hour, RoW, None)
-0.009514   'Water, turbine use, unspecified natural origin' (cubic meter, None, ('natural resource', 'in water'))
            'electricity production, hydro, run-of-river' (kilowatt hour, RoW, None)
0.007264    'Water' (cubic meter, None, ('water',))
            'electricity production, hydro, run-of-river' (kilowatt hour, FR, None)
-0.007264   'Water, turbine use, unspecified natural origin' (cubic meter, None, ('natural resource', 'in water'))
            'electricity production, hydro, run-of-river' (kilowatt hour, FR, None)
-0.003371   'Water, river' (cubic meter, None, ('natural resource', 'in water'))
            'irrigation, sprinkler' (cubic meter, CH, None)
0.003069    'Water' (cubic meter, None, ('water', 'ground-'))
            'sugar beet production' (kilogram, CH, None)
0.001935    'Water' (cubic meter, None, ('air',))
            'sugar beet production' (kilogram, CH, None)
0.001440    'Water' (cubic meter, None, ('water',))
            'electricity production, hydro, run-of-river' (kilowatt hour, CN-SC, None)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the useful reply and for confirming my intuition. I think i got a bit too deep in the code and didnt look in the correct direction though, i need to implement the AWARE impact assessment method, but i just saw on [link](https://github.com/cmutel/bw2_aware) this is already implemented! i'll leave the question though because it might be helpful for someone else

Comment: Hi chris, i updated my question because i think i migt have reached a solution, could you please check it? Thanks a lot!